# scrollTop not as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Note

> Reopening bounty as forgot to award it last time. Already being answered by Master A.Woff.

I want to reach to a certain row when a user expands it (so that when last visible row gets expanded, the user doesn't have to scroll down to see the content).

I used,

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td .green-expand', function (event, delegated) {    

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);


        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            if (event.originalEvent || (delegated && !$(delegated).hasClass('show'))) {
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }
        } else {
            if (event.originalEvent || (delegated && $(delegated).hasClass('show'))) {
                row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');

                var parent = $(this).closest('table');
                var scrollTo = $(this).closest('tr').position().top;

                $('.dataTables_scrollBody').animate({
                    scrollTop: scrollTo
                });
            }
        }
});
```

**Note**

**Expand row - just click on `click` hyperlink. It will show row details**

[Datatable with expand row](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/9bndmnmt/)

Comment: What do you mean by "expand row"?

Comment: @hindmost just check fiddle and click on `click` link

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `offsetTop` property instead to get relevant `offsetParent` (*see edit part*):

```
var scrollTo = tr.prop('offsetTop');
```

### -jsFiddle-

Or set `table` element position not static:

`table.dataTable { position: relative; }`

### -jsFiddle-

***EDIT:*** Why jq `position().top` doesn't work in this case?

This is because position is calculated regarding `offsetParent`. Natively, regarding spec, the offsetParent is the nearest ancestor with computed position not static or the `body` element or `td, th` or `table` ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-htmlelement-interface)).

This behaviour, i suspect, can return different result regarding browser implementation, following the spec or not.

So, jQuery normalizes it, not using native DOM property `offsetParent` but own method `$.fn.offsetParent()`. This method implementation is as follow:

```
offsetParent: function () {
    return this.map(function () {
        var offsetParent = this.offsetParent || docElem;

        while (offsetParent && (!jQuery.nodeName(offsetParent, "html") && jQuery.css(offsetParent, "position") === "static")) {
            offsetParent = offsetParent.offsetParent;
        }
        return offsetParent || docElem;
    });
}
```

As you can see, no element exception is done regarding any type of element (`docElem` is the current document object).
By default, `table` element position is static, that's why in your example, jq returns as `offsetParent`, the `div` wrapper used by jQuery datatable plugin and not the `table` (exception following spec). And so, native `offsetTop` property and jq `$.fn.position().top` returns different result.

> Also the currently solution does not work in all cases

Testing it on chrome (only), i cannot replicate issue.

Comment: and also it does not scroll to top every row if you can check. If I expand one row and then try expanding row above it. It fails to reach to top

Comment: Because `position()` jQuery method is relative to offset parent which here is `#example` DIV, when you want its postion relative to its parent, the `table`. Now regarding issue, i don't have enough time currently to see it more deeply, sorry. Maybe later. As a sdie note, fixing your fiddle to make table the offset parent: http://jsfiddle.net/9bndmnmt/2/

Comment: Thanks a top master @A. Wolff. I have learned many things from you.

Comment: I will try fixing this at my end and will post the answer. If you too get time please post yours answer as well

Comment: Just checked doc for offsetTop and should return same result as jq position method regarding offset parent, so im confused here. This would need more investigation. GL

Comment: Yup .. I think need to dig more. `offsetTop === position().top()`

Comment: got anything? I also tried to dig more dipper but failed to understand this behaviour

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir Regarding issue using `offsetTop`, is it the same using `table.dataTable { position: relative; }`? If ya, how exactly replicating issue? On all browsers? Because i'm unable to do it (only tested on chrome).

Comment: Issue on chrome Version 44.0.2403.155 m. even using positioned table

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir But is this issue on jsFiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/9bndmnmt/3/  or on your website or both?

Comment: only on my website. not on fiddle. (Replicated the exact code)

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir So i guess you are doing something on your website not provided in jsFiddle. Aren't you animating in some way the expanding row part? And/or collapse any previous expanded row when clicking on a new one? This would explain it

Comment: Steps 

1. Expand first row

2. Go to last row and expand it
3. Try expanding any row before last rows

I am using exactly same code for animation. I have used perfect scrollbar does it doing this?

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir Like i said and like you seem to said, it works as expected on jsFiddle so i cannot help you more without beeing able to debug the issue

Comment: Ok..I understood..sorry to trouble you..The issue lies in updating height when expand row is clicked

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir You need to debug it on your side. First thing to try is to check if issue persists removing `perfect scrollbar` plugin. If no, then you know from which part comes from the issue

Answer (score 1):

You will need to take the screen height and adjust the expanded div as per your required pixel size. We cannot directly use the scrollTop option to adjust the position in the window. These have to dynamically adjusted since it depends on various screen resolutions and sizes. See if you have more issues.

Thanks!!