# Animate not scrolling to correct row

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-animate

I've implemented a scroller in my jQuery DataTable. When the user clicks an icon on the map, the icon's ID (rowId) will be used to scroll to correct row in the table. It works for small tables but with tables with hundreds of results it doesn't scroll to the correct row. Any ideas?

```
//When click on a feature will AUTOMATICALLY scroll to that record in the table 
if (rowId != null) {
    $('.dataTables_scrollBody').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#TemplateData tbody tr').eq(rowId).offset().top
    }, 800)
}
```

Also, what does the value 800 represent?

Comment: Does it help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938508/scrolltop-not-as-expected/31938830#31938830  ? (set as CSS rule: `table.dataTable { position: relative; }`) FYI, `800` is animation duration, just check the [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: I am using offset() as opposed to offsetparent()?

Comment: Good point! So i think you should use `scrollTop: $('#TemplateData tbody tr').eq(rowId).position().top` and set as CSS rule: `table.dataTable { position: relative; }`

Comment: almost there...only problem now it is 2 rows off. So if row 168 is selected. the table will scroll to 170. How can i amend this. is it the outer div causing the issue?

Comment: As for the value 800, please see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete). That is the duration argument.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing relevant rendered HTML markup. Maybe you need to set `position: relative` to other element than the table, depending maybe some margin/padding. Maybe try: `.dataTables_scrollBody {position: relative;}`  if it is tbody, not thee table element. If you are able to provide MCVE like a jsFiddle, would be easier to check what's going on

Comment: just minus by 2 and it worked thanks for the help Wolf. stick up your answer and il mark it